Counter example to the identity theorem for two generating functions
I want to give an example of two generating functions $\psi_{X_+}$ and $\psi_{X_-}$ for random variables $X_+$ and $X_-$ with values in $\mathbb{N}_0$ which coincide on infinitely many points $x_i\in(0,1)$ but are not equal. In this case, the power series necessarily diverge for $x>1$ by the identity theorem.
I was thinking of defining $\sin\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=f_+-f_-$ where $f_+$ resp. $f_-$ are the sum of the positive resp. negative coefficients of the power series expansion of $\sin\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)$ around $x=0$. Then, $f_+$ and $f_-$ have non-negative coefficients which have a potential to be interpreted as probabilities after normalization but it seems impossible to normalize them and set $\psi_{X_+}=\frac{1}{N}f_+$, $\psi_{X_-}=\frac{1}{N}f_-$ so that $\psi_{X_+}(1)=\psi_{X_-}(1)=1$ as
$$
\lim_{x\uparrow 1}f_+(x)=\infty
$$
and the same for $f_-$.
Maybe, my "Ansatz" is false, then please correct me, because we have a singularity at $x=1$ - and I don't see how this is compatible with the normalization of the generating functions. Or otherwise, if there is no singularity at $x=1$ and just divergence for $x>1$, I can't find a nonzero example with infinitely many zeros (this sine function of a fraction with $x$ in the denominator being the standard counter example to the indentity theorem, cf. link).
"Avertissment": This is "Übung 3.1.2" in Achim Klenke's "Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie".

I think, we can take the function $(1-x)\sin\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=f_+-f_-$ with $f_+$ and $f_-$ defined as in the question. Since the left hand side converges to $0$, when $x\uparrow 1$, we can simultaneously normalize with $N=f_+(1)=f_-(1)$ if this $N$ is nonzero. But it is easy to see from the power series expansion of $\sin$ that $N\neq 0$; it is even obvious that $N=1$ and that this step in the proof is not even needed. In fact, we have
$$
f_+(1-x)=1+\frac{z^4}{5!}+\frac{z^8}{9!}+\cdots,\\
f_-(1-x)=1+\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^6}{7!}+\cdots,
$$
where $z=1/x$.

Maybe, I was a bit too rough and sloppy. But, by replacing $(1-x)$ with a function which converges even faster to $0$ for $x\uparrow 1$, we can certainly achieve $N$ is finite (modulo details) without changing the singularity at $x=1$ and the essential idea of the proof.
